# Is there a way to iterate over a table value in Lua?

Tags: dictionary, lua, call

I have the following table in Lua:

`local a = {orszag = {"Ausztria", "Albánia", "Azerbajdzsán"}, varos = {"Ankara", "Amszterdam", "Antwerpen"}, fiu = {"Arnold", "Andor", "Albert"}, lany = {"Anna", "Anasztázia", "Amanda"}}`

I would like to do the following:

`for i in a["orszag"] do etc.` (for example compare all the words in the value to the user input)

But when I do so I get the following: attempt to call a table value.

So I know, it works in python for example, but is it possible somehow to do this in Lua as well?

Comment: Please read the Lua manual it's just a few pages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
for k,v in pairs(a["orszag"]) do
```